# Error : Value of type 'String' has no member 'URLByAppendingPathComponent'

Tags: ios, swift

My Error is:
**Value of type 'String' has no member 'URLByAppendingPathComponent'**

I got error in this line :

```
 let savePath = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")
```

My full code:

```
  // 4 - Get path
  let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] 
  var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
  dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
  let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
  let savePath = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)
```

I followed this tutorial : [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/94404/play-record-merge-videos-ios-swift)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's

```
let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")
```

since `documentDirectory` is a `String` rather than an `NSURL`

**Edit**

I recommend to use this API:

```
let documentDirectory = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
let saveURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov") // now it's NSURL
```

Swift 3+

```
let documentDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
let saveURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")
```

Comment: yes after change that line  got error: `'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use URLByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead.`

Comment: I updated the answer fixing the problem. It might be preferable to use the URL related API anyway (getting the URL with `NSFileManager`).

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, there is no `URLByAppendingPathComponent` method available for `String` class, that function belongs to [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/URLByAppendingPathComponent:).

You need to use:

```
let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")
```

Or you can do it like:

```
let url      = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
let savePath = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay solution

Comment: @user5513630: That's due to swift 2.0, I'm updating my answer with another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3: URL appendingPathComponent

```
    let documentDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let completeMovie = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("movie.mov") // now it's NSURL
```

Swift 3 Path

```
  let fm = FileManager.default

        let docsurl = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let completeMovie = String(describing: docsurl.appendingPathComponent("merge.mp4"))
```